# Spree and rails - uninitialized constant ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have an issue with the command

```
rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User
```

I'm following the Spree guide from github : https://github.com/spree/spree

ans i have the error :

```
Uninitialize constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

I use ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.7.1 and Spree 3.0.10

Here my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails'#, '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'gem 
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spree', '~> 3.0.10'
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Update the gem version and check once again. `sudo gem update --system`

Comment: I already tried. I tried again for you and i have Lastest version currently installed

Comment: For an older version I saw that adding `require 'thread'` in boot.rb file on the top solves it. Check whether it solves the issue.

Comment: still not working. same error

Answer (score 0):

I think i found why it don't work. The project was created with rails 5.0.0.1 then i downgrade to 4.7.1 to be able to use spree.

Spree isn't compatible with rails 5 and some files are from the command line to create project on rails 5

I'm not sure at all but i guess i just can't use spree with this project. I must restart